# How can I make my quiz app not have a random answer in each question?

Tags: app-inventor

I make a quiz app with MIT app inventor 2 and didn't know how to change the block code so the answer list not displaying random answer in the application.

This is my List, there is 3 List, 1. List of Questions, 2. List of Answers and 3. List of Button_Component:

[image: image1]

The procedure that I have for each questions, so it display the quiz app, but still random:

[image: image2]

I had changed the block of random integer and replace it with get value in length of list, but my answer list not display in button_component. I got stuck in this, and hope you know the solution. Really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: [A Multiple Choice Quiz: How to work with the advanced features](https://puravidaapps.com/quiz.php)

Comment: Thank you, Taifun. I will learn from the link. How many List of component can app inventor provide? Cause I use for 80-100 questions the application when installed in device is not working, but when used in online (via AI companion) the app is working (with 80-100 list of questions).

Comment: for larger lists store your questions in a textfile and load it into a list using the file component on first run of the app... btw. stackoverflow is not a forum, but a question and answer site, so follow up questions are not part of stackoverflow's philosophy... you might want to ask in the App Inventor forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest next time...

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you again, Taifun.